# Inserting a page break in Crystal Reports programmatically

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How do I insert a page break in Crystal Reports. Using VB.Net, not in the report definition?

Answer (score 0):

The best technique I've used for stuff like this is to group on a formula.  Set the report to break on that formula, then you can set the value of the formula in your .Net code to a value that'll break where you want to break.

Using this technique, you can create a single report and have it dynamically sort and break on any field (or formula) you want at runtime, which makes the report very versatile.